# What does sessionStore.close() actually do in `express-mysql-session`?

Tags: mysql, session, express

It is not clear [from documentation](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session#closing-the-session-store) what this operation does.

> **Closing the session store**
>
> To cleanly close the session store:
>
> `sessionStore.close();`

What does actually `close the session store` mean?

I need to sign out a user. I merely need to delete a session record from a DB. Do I need *close the session store* in order to achieve it?

Comment: From the source, calling `sessionStore.close()` ends the db connection. https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session/blob/master/lib/index.js#L370

Answer (score 2):

In order to destroy a session

```
router.route('/logout')
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            return res.redirect(302, '/login');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session/blob/master/lib/index.js#L370), calling `sessionStore.close()` ends the db connection.

To logout the user, you can either

- destroy the session by calling `req.session.destroy()`
- or, if you are using passport.js, call `req.logOut()`